# CouchDB include document in index if count of array field is greater than 0

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, database, nosql

I am using Cloudant which is just CouchDB with some more features and I'm looking for the syntax to count the number of elements in an array. Specifically, I'm creating a design document where I only index the document if its field 'color' has more than 0 elements. How do I check to see if there are more than 0 elements in 'color'?

```
{"_id": "_design/geodd",
 "_rev": "5-2729b1453b11f81261ddb3cf3f3de72f",
 "st_indexes": {
  "geoidx": {
   "index": "function(doc) {if (doc.geometry && doc.geometry.coordinates && doc.color != []) {st_index(doc.geometry);}}"
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing your view, you can execute any Javascript code, so this is more a javascript question than a CouchDB question.

The mistake in your view is that you cannot compare arrays in javascript with the equality operator: `doc.color != []` will always return false (because they are not the same objects).

Try replacing this by `doc.color.length == 0` if you know in advance that `doc.color` is always an array.

If your not sure `doc.color` is an array, write `isArray(doc.color) && doc.color.length == 0`.

Your view code would become:

```
{"_id": "_design/geodd",
 "_rev": "5-2729b1453b11f81261ddb3cf3f3de72f",
 "st_indexes": {
  "geoidx": {
   "index": "function(doc) {if (doc.geometry && doc.geometry.coordinates && isArray(doc.color) && doc.color.length == 0) {st_index(doc.geometry);}}"
  }
 }
}
```